# SQL 2012 bcp call returns SQLState = 28000. NativeError = 18456 Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, bcp, xp-cmdshell

I’m working with a SQL stored procedure that makes a call to xp_cmdshell.   xp_cmdshell has been enabled, and has a proxy account set to ‘vpexporter’.  This sproc was designed to write out a data file to disk.

This sproc had been working when it was on a SQL 2005 server. The environment has been upgraded to SQL 2012 and the sproc no longer runs.  The line making the call is:

```
set @sql1 = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM dbo.udPayrollOutput" queryout "D:\Repository\Exports\' + @fileunique  -Uvpexporter -Ppassword -c -t,' 
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql1
```

Running this in SSMS gives me the following:

> SQLState = 28000. NativeError = 18456 Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server
>   Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user ‘vpexporter’.

I have tried this with both a SQL login and with a domain account.  Both return the same error.  The ‘vpexporter’ has been added as a login, and has been set up as a user of the master db with execute permissions on xp_cmdshell.

I feel something must have changed in how xp_cmdshell is called with SQL version 2012, but I haven’t found anything when googling that.

I tried running "exec xp_cmdshell 'whoami.exe'"  which returned 'nt authority\network service' which is the account SQL Server is running under.

My understanding was that by specifying a command shell proxy account with 'sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account' it would use that instead.  I do not want to grant xp_cmdshell execute access to the Network Service.

---

I've made some progress but am still getting stuck. The original error was due to the new environment requiring specifying the SQL instance by adding "-S ServerName\InstanceName"  to my query line.  I now get the error:

> Unable to launch 'cvADPTaxCreditExp' stored procedure.
>   The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_cmdshell', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

I have granted Execute permission to xp_cmdshell in master to the proxy account, but am still getting this error.

```
exec sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'NEWMECHDOM\vpexporter', 'password';
GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_cmdshell TO [NEWMECHDOM\vpexporter];
```

I have verified it with this:

```
select  * from  sys.credentials
```

Is there someplace else security needs to be set?

Comment: Executing `xp_cmdshell 'whoami.exe'`; does that return what you'd expect?

Comment: @Mackan,   I tried running "exec xp_cmdshell 'whoami.exe'" which returned 'nt authority\network service' which is the account SQL Server is running under.

My understanding was that by specifying a command shell proxy account with 'sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account' it would use that instead. I do not want to grant xp_cmdshell execute access to the Network Service.

Comment: It should, as far as I know, be using the proxy account if you've set it up correctly (and if it has enough rights). `EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'DOMAIN\user','password'`. If running through a sysadmin account, xp_cmdshell will use the service account to spawn child processes though.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem using `bcp.exe` in a batch file running on a SQL Server 2008 R2 machine: specifying user/password with `-U -P` was returning "NativeError = 18456" (login failed) and I resolved it using "trusted connection" with parameter `-T`.

`BCP.EXE` call WITH ERROR 18456 was:

```
bcp.exe "SELECT * from DWH.BS.flussi.vw_KLINX_Anagrafiche800" queryout %fname% -t";" -c -SLOCALHOST -dMEF -Uxxx -Pyyy
```

`BCP.EXE` WORKING call is:

```
bcp.exe "SELECT * from DWH.BS.flussi.vw_KLINX_Anagrafiche800" queryout %fname% -t";" -c -SLOCALHOST -dMEF -Uxxx -Pyyy -T
```

Comment: Did you had to plaintext your password PLUS add the -T (trusted) option? Seems like a doable solution that nonethless raises a security issue (showing the password in plaintext).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that 2008 is not the same as 2012.  In 2008 I didn't need to specify the Server Name.  In 2008 I was also able to use a drive letter using D$, but now I needed to use a Shared drive name.  The following works in 2012.

```
-- Declare report variables
DECLARE @REPORT_DIR VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @REPORT_FILE VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @DATETIME_STAMP VARCHAR(14)
DECLARE @Statement VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @Command VARCHAR(4000)

--SET variables for the Report File
SET @DATETIME_STAMP = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112) + 
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(),108),':','')) -- Date Time Stamp with YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
SET @REPORT_DIR = '\\aServerName\SharedDirectory\' -- Setting where to send the report. The Server name and a Shared name, not a drive letter
SET @REPORT_FILE = @REPORT_DIR + 'Tables_' + @DATETIME_STAMP + '.csv' --the -t below is used for the csv file
```

--Create the CSV file report with all of the data. The @Statement variable must be used to use variables in the xp_cmdshell command.

```
SET @Statement = '"SELECT * FROM  sys.tables" queryout "'+@REPORT_FILE+'" -c -t"," -r"\n" -S"CurrentServerName\Databasename" -T' --The -S must be used with the -T
SET @Command = 'bcp '+@Statement+' '
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @Command
```