# Bcp.exe throws login failed with error code 18456 using -U parameter

Tags: sql-server, bcp

The `bcp.exe` utility throws *login failed* for a user belonging to a different domain. I can't use the `-T` parameter since there is no trust between the two domains. I need to use only Windows type of authentication (SQL Server Authentication not supported).

I am able to use the same credentials while executing a query. Everything works fine. But in `bcp.exe` the error 18456 is thrown.

Is there any way to provide the user name and password for the `bcp.exe` utility for Windows type of authentication instead of the `-T` parameter?

Comment: post the entire error message

Comment: `C:\ManageEngine_new\ADSelfService Plus\bin>bcp.exe adssp82389.dbo.ADSMUserReportResult in "C:/ManageEngine_new/ADSelfService Plus/temp/ADSMUserReportResult_1481644888485.txt" -S VIGNESH-1878\SQLEXPRESS01 -U vignesh-1878@csez.zohocorpin.com -P xxxxxxx SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'vignesh-1878@csez.zohocorpin.com'.`

Comment: does your server supports sql authentication

Comment: does this help :http://www.sqlserverblogforum.com/2012/06/login-failed-for-sqlstate-28000-error-18456-the-step-failed/

Comment: and this as well:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611600/sql-2012-bcp-call-returns-sqlstate-28000-nativeerror-18456-login-failed-for

Comment: You're using `-U` and `-P` (SQL authentication) but you say it doesn't support it? Perhaps to save confusion, remove the `-U` and `-P` parameters and only use `-T`. To use a specific windows user, you need to `Run As` a cmd window as the user and use the `-T` parameter